# Using Java classes from native activity android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm working on an Android application that is currently written fully in C++, implemented as a Native Activity and using CMake to build the project.

Currently, I'm looking at trying to call methods in a Java derived WebView class from C++, but am having difficulties with how to use build/use this class with the Native Activity.

My `build.gradle` is located in the root of the project, and all of the C++ code is in `src/`. Simply adding the Java file to the project, under `src/main/java/com/my/app/CustomWebView.java`.

and calling:

```cpp
JNIEnv * env = 0; 
JNIEnv ** envptr = &env; 
JavaVM * jniiptr = gapp->activity->vm; 
jniiptr->AttachCurrentThread( (JNIEnv**)&env, 0 ); 
env = (*envptr);
jclass customWebViewClass = env->FindClass("com/my/app/CustomWebView");
```

Results in `customWebViewClass` being null.

I am unsure on what I need to do for this to be found correctly. I haven't yet modified any build or manifest files (such as `build.gradle` or `AndroidManifest.xml`), and was wondering if I needed to for this java class to be found correctly?

Comment: JNIEnv * env = 0; 
JNIEnv ** envptr = &env;   So you're making a null pointer, then a pointer to a null pointer?  That's not right, and I'm shocked it didn't crash.

Comment: doing that is fine (it is taking the address of the variable `env` which is not what is null...) where I am having difficulty is elsewhere in the code sample. Might you have insights into that? That code to get `env` is used elsewhere in the codebase and functions ok.

Comment: Unrelated but assigning 0 to a pointer is a bad practice. Use `nullptr` if your compiler supports it or at least `NULL`.

Comment: Reminder:  Java has garbage collection.  There is no guarantee when or if the garbage collector runs.  This is usually bad for embedded systems.

Comment: You should check the result of every JNI operation. And why assign (*envptr) to env? Makes no sense